# Long author names in BibTeX entry causes text to go over margins. How can I allow or force text breaks?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have a reference in my BibTeX bibliography file that has some really long author names:

```
@inproceedings{foo,
  title={Data Augmentation Using GANs for Speech Emotion Recognition},
  author={Chatziagapi, Aggelina and Paraskevopoulos, Georgios and Sgouropoulos, Dimitris and Pantazopoulos, Georgios and Nikandrou, Malvina and Giannakopoulos, Theodoros and Katsamanis, Athanasios and Potamianos, Alexandros and Narayanan, Shrikanth},
  booktitle={Proceedings of INTERSPEECH},
  pages={171--175},
  year={2019}
}
```

[image]

As you can see, reference [41] has some of the author names go over the margin. It seems to me that the compiler correctly breaks Sgouropoulos but not Giannakopoulos or Narayanan.

How do I allow or force line breaks in this situation?

Compilers used is PdfLaTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 + Bib(la)tex 0.99d + PdfLaTeX (x2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX is not very good at hyphenating some of your authors' names. You need to give it some help.

```
% namesprob.tex  SE 571116
\documentclass{article}
%\hyphenation{Gian-nak-opou-los}
%\hyphenation{Nar-aya-nam} % Try this, or similar, for hyphenation
\begin{document}
\textbf{Default hyphenation}

\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}
 % \mbox{} is because LaTeX won't hyphenate first word in a paragraph
\mbox{} Giannakopoulos 

\mbox{} Narayanam % LaTex doesn't know how to hyphenate this
\end{minipage}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\textbf{Now with user-defined hyphenation}

\begin{minipage}{0.5cm}
\hyphenation{Gian-nak-opou-los}
\hyphenation{Nar-aya-nam} % Try this, or similar, for hyphenation
\mbox{} Giannakopoulos 

\mbox{} Narayanam % You have now told LaTex hyphenate this
\end{minipage}
    
\end{document}
```

Use the `\hyphenation` macro to specify hyphenation positions.

[image]

Comment: Should it be `\hyphenation{Gian-nak-opou-los}` or `\hyphenation{Gian-na-ko-pou-los}`?

Comment: @Mico I have no idea. I just ignorantly chose some hyphenation points as examples.